# Problem uploading images using ImageField in Django on Heroku

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, amazon-s3

I have an ImageField and I'm also using AWS S3.

Locally whenever I upload an image this works perfectly and I am able to upload the image and view it.

However, when I try to upload an image on heroku I get this error:

```
expected string or bytes-like object
```

For my ImageField in my models.py it is:

```
image = models.ImageField(blank=False)
```

In settings.py I have:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'the location im using'
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

So not quite sure how to fix it so it works in heroku like it does locally.

Thanks

Comment: do you see any errors? 

is django-storages (with requirements) in your `requirements.txt` (or `Pipfile`)?

Comment: Yes I have django-storages==1.8 in my requirements.txt

Comment: What are you dong when you see that error? Is it when you try to upload a new file? when you try to render it in a template? Something else? Please read [ask].

Comment: I made the appropriate edits, its for whenever I upload an image.

Comment: @user8802333 can you add the complete stack-trace of the error / the exception? 

Currently my best guess: one of the environment variables you use to set some settings does not exist (access-key, secret-key, storage-bucket).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.

I didn't put my environment variables into heroku (the hosting service I am using). That is why it worked locally but not on heroku.

In the terminal I just had to do this for all the relevant environment variables:

```
heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME="joesmith"
```

More information [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)